# kendo grid column header in 2 level

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I use kendo ui grid
I want to make a grid that had 2 level header column like the image below:
[image]

I has 3 header , 12 sub header and for data it has 12 column
Can i make this by kendo grid?

Answer (score 0):

You could be patient and use [Kendo header template](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/toolbar-template.html):

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
                <div class="toolbar k-grid-header k-grid-header-wrap">
                   <table role="grid">
                     <colgroup>
                        <col style="width:200px">
                        <col>
                        <col style="width:100px">
                        <col>
                     </colgroup>
                     <thead role="rowgroup">
                     <tr role="row">
                        <th role="columnheader" class="k-header">Column level 2</th>
                        <th role="columnheader" class="k-header">Column level 2</th>
                      </tr>
                      </thead>
                   <table>
                </div>
            </script>

 var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
     toolbar: kendo.template($("#template").html()) 
  });
```

This solution will obviously not support dynamic column width and similar features you will have at the level 1 columns.